# Google Analytics Goal Completed but not Showing

Tags: google, google-analytics, goal-tracking, goals

I have `Goal 1` set up in Google Analytics, with `/thank-you/` as a goal completion destination page that a user goes to after signing up on my Mailchimp list.

Although I get a non-zero conversion when I click on `Re-verify`

[image]

it still shows Zero goals in the Goals Overview page.

[image]

**Question:** How should I configure my goals for them to show up on the Goals Overview page?

Comment: How long have you waited for the goal to come through to the reporting dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait at least 24 hours for data to be processed into your standard GA reports. You could also try to verify in your Real-Time reports where you will see the conversion increase if it is successfully tracked.